# Insert linebreak before or after a float

Tags: floats, line-breaking

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] \\
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a figure caption.}
    \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

Which gives the following output:

[image: MWE for a linebreak after a figure]

Why do I get that small indent before the start of the new line ("Suspendisse ...")? And how can I avoid that?

I know I could leave a blank line and use `\noindent`, but is this the only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Float (even with `h`) is logically not part of the document flow, it is a insert added later to the document, so ideally the markup would be a new paragraph, or if it isn't a paragraph, no forced line break.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a figure caption.}
    \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a figure caption.}
    \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If logically it makes sense to force a line break, use `\end{figure}%`

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\\
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a figure caption.}
    \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}%
\lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

But this forces a linebreak irrespective of the position of the figure so should only be done if it is needed for the text. If the figure floats to the next page, the linebreak is still at the orginal place.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]\\
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a figure caption.}
    \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}%
\lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `\newline` after the figure.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]  
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image-a}
        \caption{This is a figure caption.}
        \label{fig:figure1}
    \end{figure}\newline % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```